# Zebra QLN320 & Zebra Print Station

Tags: bluetooth, zebra-printers, zpl

I've had a ZPL file created for me (well, a few different varieties) that has variables inside.

I've sent it to the printer via Zebra Setup Utilities and when I try and access it from the Print Station App on Galaxy Note 8, I get the error: "Could not retrieve format list from the specified printer"

The printer is connected via Bluetooth and it has been set up via the USB cable and connectivity options in the Zebra Setup Utilities. The sample files (Oilchange.zpl and address.zpl) work correctly and populate the data.

The weird thing is that yesterday, the format was being populated, yet it would not print out the variables on the labels.

All of my zpl files are located at www.gungetankhire.com/zpl

I really hope someone can talk me through this - I need this working for an exhibition on Monday

Many Thanks

Leigh

Comment: Can you provide some context? What is your ultimate goal? How does this fit into your process/goal?

Comment: I want to create a simple label that has product name, scent, colour, date and customer name on it. This needs to be printed via my Galaxy Note 8 (Bluetooth), rather than linked to a laptop computer

Answer (score 1):

The field for Product in your Leigh2.zpl looks like the following
^FO248,224^ADN,36,20^FDProduct^FS

In order to get it to become a variable the user needs to enter you can update it to the following
^FO248,224^A0N,30,24^FN1"Product"^FS

You will notice it has changed from using ^FD to ^FN.
the 1 following the FN is the field number and then I added quotes around Product to name the field. The number for the field is unique, if you have 6 fields each one should have its own number 1-6. The field name is not needed but if not used the Print Station App will show "Field 1" for ^FN1. If you update the fields you want as variables to this format you should be able to enter the values on Print Station and print them out on your label.